# Unclogging bathtub with an external tower drain

Tags: plumbing, drain, bathtub, drain-waste-vent

I have a clog in my bathtub. There is no visible overflow and it has an external tower drain. When I try to snake through the tub drain the snake comes up the external tower. Do I need to remove the tower and snake through it? If so, how? I've snaked and succeeded unclogging drains but this is the first time encountering an external tower drain.

Comment: Picture might help with all the drain configurations out there, but the ones I've seen, the tower just unscrews from the rest of the drain assembly.

Answer (score 1):

I think what happened is, when the snake got to the "T" where the horizontal pipe meets the tower, it went UP.

A metal snake is always bent a little, which makes it tend to go one way or the other when it gets to a junction.  If you remove the tape, turn it over, and reinsert it, it might go DOWN instead when it gets to the "T" - the bend in the tape will make the tip point down instead of up.

But it would be easier to just snake straight down the tower.  You have cleared the pip from the drain to the T, so going straight down the tower should be fine.

Just remember to go nice and easy with the snake!